# Use SignalR along with ASP.Net WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr

I read a lot about SignalR and wondering about how to use it with ASP.NET WebAPI. It seems that the WebAPI route config made the SignalR connection not able to connect to Hub and I don't know how to set up correctly to make this 2 things work together.

Answer (score 1):

The two should not conflict if you have not configured the webapi framework to override some of SignalR default routes like `~/signalr/hubs`

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRConfig))]
namespace MyApp.App_Start
{
    public static class SignalRConfig
    {
        public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Thats what you need for signalr to hook up, and then include the client side scripts

`@Scripts.Render("~/signalr/hubs")` and `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-{version}.js")`

Here is an example were I use them together

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4